# Docker throwing SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Tags: javascript, docker, express, dockerfile

I've got a very simple project express app. I've dockerized the app but Im having issues running the `docker run` command.

I keep on seeing this error when I run `docker run test -p 8080:3000`

```
docker run test -p 8080:3000
[eval]:1
8080:3000
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at new Script (vm.js:99:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:249:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:297:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:10:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:30)
    at evalScript (internal/process/execution.js:94:25)
    at internal/main/eval_string.js:23:3
```

my dockerfile looks llike this:

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN apk update && apk add python make g++
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

If I run `docker run imageName`, it's fine the container starts. But because I don't have port mapping I cant make use of the app.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is with the command Im running. Instead of running `docker run test -p 8080:3000` it should have been `docker run -p 8080:3000 test`.

Comment: Just a note that your original order of arguments worked fine for me on Mac OS (11.6) but I needed to used your revised order on Oracle Linux 8.5.